# Nodejs: TypeError: require().() is not a func

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Im trying to resolve the issue I encounter when Im trying to update jest in my package.json

jest 26.6.3  →   27.0.1

Im receiving error

```
TypeError: require(...).createTransformer is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/local/repo/elukchm/monorepo/packages/edf/jestPreprocess.js:34:40)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
```

The code mentioned in files:

**jestPreprocess.js**

```
const babelOptions = {
...
};

module.exports = require("babel-jest").createTransformer(babelOptions);
```

**Inside "babel-jest"**

```
const createTransformer = userOptions => {
var _inputOptions$plugins, _inputOptions$presets;

const inputOptions =
userOptions !== null && userOptions !== void 0 ? userOptions : {};
const options = {
...
};
```

Could you please take a look and tell what should I change? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

`babel-jest@27` [switched to ESM](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/11193), so `require` is now getting the whole exported scope rather than just the default. Super simple to fix:

```
module.exports = require("babel-jest").createTransformer(babelOptions);
-->
module.exports = require("babel-jest").default.createTransformer(babelOptions);
```